# Solve the initial value problem $xy'(x) = y, y(0)=0,x≥0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem $xy'(x) = y, y(0)=0,x≥0$

My attempt:

$\frac{dy}{y} = \frac{dx}{x}$

$ \text{ln}y = \text{ln}x + c$ ..... $(1)$

Now $c$ can't be find because $0$ is not in domain of log function, so there should be no solution.

Or in other way-

Equation $(1)$ can be written as $y = c_{1} x$

No we can have uncountable solutions.

Which one is the right method$?$

Comment: The fact that you cannot find $c$ doesn't mean that there is no solution. And when you write $y=c_1x$, you cannot find $c_1$ either.

Answer (score 2):

$y=cx$ is a correct solution.

The problem with the integration is that the first line of your proof depends upon $x$ and $y$ being non-zero so that you can divide by them.

So your method shows that $y=cx$ for $x,y>0$. Then you are simply spotting that it's also fine for $x=y=0$.

Comment: So it has uncountable solutions$?$

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 1):

You can write

$$x,y\ne0\implies\frac{dy}y=\frac{dx}x\implies \log y=\log x+c\implies y=cx$$

and $c$ is indeterminate.

Now,

- if $x=0$, the equation reduces to $y(0)=0$, and
- if $y=0$, $xy'=0$ requires $x=0\lor y'=0$, and the last condition is $y=c$. But as $y$ must be differentiable at $x=0$, we have $c=0$.

Hence, the rigorous analysis concludes

$$y=cx\lor y=0$$ which can be summarized by $$y=cx.$$